# VTK and Python rendering

Tags: python, windows, vtk

I am attempting to get VTK working with Python on my Windows 7 32 bit PC at work. I am running Python 2.7. 
Basically, if I write a simple code to render a cylinder as follows:

```
import vtk
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()

iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

source = vtk.vtkCylinderSource()
source.SetCenter(0,0,0)
source.SetRadius(5.0)
source.SetHeight(7.0)
source.SetResolution(100)

mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInutConnection(source.GetOuputPort())

actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

ren.AddActor(actor)

iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start
```

If I try and run this from idle, I get the graphic apeparing in a new window as I would expect but after a few seconds it goes white and unresponsive and I get a 'Not Responding' in the Task Manager. I read online that this may be idle so I ran it from the command prompt. This time it appears for a second or two and then the script finishes and it closes. If I put it into a infinite loop then the same thing as before happens - unresponsive. I think the answer is something to do with keeping the window open until I update the parameters but not rendering cosntantly? Or I could be way off.

This is just to get it working properly so I can start my actual project. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You missed to attach the renderer to the renderwindow. renWin.AddRenderer(ren)

Comment: Also, it should be `iren.Start()`.

Comment: Cheers for these, will try them later today